# Stuck Outside of Map in Assassins Creed Rogue In New York

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-rogue

I was running along and then I think I kind of managed to run...into... some crates instead of up them. I fell below the map (I guess below because if I move certain ways, I splash into water. Especially if I jump.) I can still move around the map (albeit weirdly) by moving and then checking my position in the Map (Back/Select Button) I was even able to start a memory, but I seriously doubt I'll be able to finish it from underneath. I there a way I can try to get out? It looks like just a grey black screen with flashes of white/grey around the screen that look roughly like the scenery to me. (Trees and buildings and such)

- I tried fast traveling: It just says Fast Travel Unavailable (even before I started the memory when I was just walking around)
- Starting a memory I saw the cutscene, although large portions of it werent visible (IE People weren't visible, but their hair, lots of clothing, and swords, guns, and such were visible) Sometimes a wall was visible.
- Exiting the memory I had started
- Getting killed (apparently I can pick fights with them, even hit them. Just blindly so. If I get killed I still wake up underneath)
- Exiting the animus playing in the abstergo building is fine. Just not much I can do since I'm not further in the story.
- Exiting to main menu and going back in (Abstergo stays fine, animus if screwed up)
- Restarting and cold booting xbox just for good measure. No effect.
- Throwing a rope dart (I have no idea what at). This would FLASH the regular minimap up briefly before going back to nothing
- Starting a new game in another slot. The Issue Persists INTO this new save game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the New game and the issue persisting into the NEW save slot made me suspect a problem with the game's underlying files (not just something with the save)

I went out to the main menu of the xBox -> System -> Storage -> Assassin's Creed Rogue -> Removed the "Install" one (It listed it as a saved game, but the title of the file mentions it's the install.) This is the 1GB of storage you have to install once the Game disc gets inserted the first time.

Delete this file (just be sure to leave the saves you want - They'll be numbered) and Open the game again. 
It goes through the intro and asks to install the 1GB of files. Let it do it's install thing, bring the save back up, and it works like normal now!